# "If you can't save him, well, there's more where he came from..."

Tags: riddle, story

The Riddler has kidnapped, of all people, a pig farmer.  Batman, as ever, must solve a riddle on the display of whatever deathtrap the farmer is strapped to in order to save the poor man.  Hence:

> My beginning is a giant's satellite.
>
> My third is, without what is most common, all we are left with.
>
> My ending is the beginning of all things.
>
> My whole is one of existence, of denial, of decay.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are

> IOWA.

*My beginning is a giant's satellite.*

> **IO** is a moon (satellite) of Jupiter (a gas giant).

*My third is, without what is most common, all we are left with.*

> **W** is all that's left of "we" after the most common letter (E) is removed.

*My ending is the beginning of all things.*

> **A** is the beginning of "all things".

*My whole is one of existence, of denial, of decay.*

> Iowa is a US state - perhaps where the farmer comes from? As @Rubio suggests in a comment, the significance of this line may be that the word "*state*" often precedes "of existence", "of denial", or "of decay".

---

**Feedback section**

As you can probably tell from the timestamps, this riddle was fairly easy, but not completely straightforward - it did require some thinking. The word "satellite" immediately made me think of moons, but the fact that "My beginning" refers to more than one letter was unexpected. Things like "what is most common" almost always refers to the letter E in puzzles like this, but finding the word "we" was another non-trivial part. And "the beginning of all things" could have been either A or AT, so we need to think about context (all the clues fitting together) to be sure of the right answer.

Comment: what's your record again? :P

Comment: @thecoder16 [38 seconds.](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/79305/fastest-answers-in-all-tags?tagname=%25)

Comment: Iowa happens to be the state with the most pig farmers.  Well done, especially for someone without knowledge of US geography!

Comment: @Exal Thanks! I added a feedback section so you can see which parts were easier/harder :-)

Comment: Can someone edit the answer to explain how it relates to existence, denial, and decay?

Comment: @shoover and @​Randal'Thor You might want to contemplate your state of existence. Also, people hiding from reality are in a state of denial, and neglected infrastructure is generally in a state of decay.